# XSLT как написать микро шаблон

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть xml

```
<Test>
  <data_type>string</data_type>
  <value>1000.00</value>
</Test>
<OBJECTIVE>
  <data_type>string</data_type>
  <value>string</value>
</OBJECTIVE>
<EDITIONDATE>
  <data_type>string</data_type>
  <value>string</value>
  <date_format>yyyyDDD</date_format>
</EDITIONDATE>
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
<Test>
  <data_type>numeric</data_type>
  <value>-1</value>
</Test>
<OBJECTIVE>
  <data_type>text</data_type>
  <value>string</value>
</OBJECTIVE>
<EDITIONDATE>
  <data_type>date</data_type>
  <value>1900</value>
  <date_format>DD-MM-yyyy</date_format>
</EDITIONDATE>
```

То что у меня есть

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="string(.)"/>
<xsl:template match="//value">
  <xsl:variable name="var" select="string(.)"/>
  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="parent::*/date_format">
      <xsl:call-template name="date_format">
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="$var = 'string'">
      <!--Передаем значение var-->
      <xsl:call-template name="text">
        <xsl:with-param name="var" select="parent::*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$var = '1000.00'">
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Я использую value, и в зависимости от него value = 1000.00, хотел бы чтоб вставлялась

```
<data_type>numeric</data_type>
<value>-1</value>
```

Если value = string то проверить нет ли на одном уровне с ним date_format если есть то

```
<data_type>date</data_type>
<value>1900</value>
<date_format>DD-MM-yyyy</date_format>
```

Если нет date_format, то

```
<data_type>text</data_type>
<value>string</value>
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:variable name="content">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:choose>
                <!-- value = 1000.00 -->
                <!-- начало -->
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'data_type' and .//following-sibling::value[text() = '1000.00']">
                    <xsl:text>num</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="text()='1000.00'">
                  <xsl:text>-1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- конец -->
                <!-- value = string -->
                <!-- начало -->
                <!-- date_format != '' -->
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'data_type'
                  and .//following-sibling::value[text() = 'string']
                  and .//following-sibling::date_format != ''">
                  <xsl:text>data</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'value'
                  and .//following-sibling::date_format != ''">
                    <xsl:text>1900</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name()='date_format'">
                  <xsl:text>DD-MM-yyyy</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- date_format = '' -->
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'data_type' 
                  and .//following-sibling::value[text() = 'string']
                  and count(.//following-sibling::date_format) = 0">
                    <xsl:text>text</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'value'">
                  <xsl:if test="count(.//following-sibling::date_format) = 0
                    and count(.//following-sibling::date_format) = 0">
                    <xsl:text>string</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- конец -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- value = string конец -->
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: получилось немного костыльно, но работает

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вроде исправлено, посмотрите